# What is the favorite pokemons feature good for?

Tags: pokemon-go

You can star your pokemon and then order your pokemon list which brings the starred pokemon to the top.

Is this favorite pokemon feature only good for organizing and ordering pokemon, or does it have other uses? Like does it prioritize pokemon in gym battles?

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

The favorite star is just for sorting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from it's CP, pokemon act differently in battle. Not sure if it's the size/height; but some move faster, etc. So you can star the one's you feel comfortable with and then it's much easier to select the right pokemon for your Gym Battle's

Comment: Right, so for sorting purposes like the answer before you stated.  What does your answer add that the other does not already provide?

Comment: @JAL it helps him get a better idea of how to sort and use the star to better effectiveness